# Scraping table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In this first code, I can use BS to get all the info within the table of interest:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for i in soup.find("table",{"id":"giftList"}).children:
    print child
```

That prints the product lists.

I want to print the rows in the `tournamentTable` [here](http://www.oddsportal.com/hockey/russia/khl/results/#/page/2.html) (desired info is in `class=deactivate`, `class=odd deactivate` and date in `class=center nob-border`):

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://www.oddsportal.com/hockey/russia/khl/results/#/page/2.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

#for i in soup.find("table",{"id":"tournamentTable"}).children:
#    print i
for i in soup.find("table",{"class":"table-main"}).children:
    print i
```

But that's printing other tables on the page. When I try to specify the table of interest with `{"id":"tournamentTable"}` it returns `Nonetype`.

What am I missing that I can't access the desired table & the information within?

Comment: maybe this part is created by JavaScript - urllib/bs doesn't works with javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `urllib.urlopen` returns the content of a webpage, it returns the HTML from a URL with JavaScript *turned off*. In your case, this means that when `urllib` loads the relevant URL, the table with `id="tournamentTable"` never actually loads.

You can observe this behaviour by *turning off JavaScript* in your browser and loading the URL.

To scrape a webpage with content rendered by JavaScript you might want to consider using a browser automation package such as **Selenium**. If you scrape regularly you might also want to download a 'JavaScript switcher' plugin which allows you to toggle JavaScript on and off with ease.