# Scraping table with BeautifulSoup, How to separate the elements with a newline?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is how the rows of my HTML table looks like:

```
<tr class='row'><td>100
    <td >George</a>
    <td class=a>123<td class=a>321
    <td>Alby<td>Dalton
```

This is my python code:

```
for tr in tabel.find('tr'):
    td = tr.find('td')
    print(td.text)
```

My output:

```
100
George
123321
AlbyDalton
```

The output that I would like to get:

```
100
George
123
321
Alby
Dalton
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping table with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119529/scraping-table-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: @AaronMorefield That does not answer the OP's question. The OP wants to separate the values with a newline instead of them being joined together...

Comment: Holy bad HTML! Was that hand-crafted in the 1990s?

Comment: I guess it was wrote around 2004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method with adding a newline `\n` as the `separator` argument.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<tr class='row'><td>100
    <td >George</a>
    <td class=a>123<td class=a>321
    <td>Alby<td>Dalton
    """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all("tr", class_="row"):
    print(tag.get_text(separator="\n", strip=True))
```

Output:

```
100
George
123
321
Alby
Dalton
```